# keydown fire multiple times with on() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('keydown','.text',function(){
                if($(this).val().length >= 3){
                    alert('d');
                }
            });
```

why my alert fire 4 times when there were 4 character? I want to execute something when the character is exceeding or equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy and paste your code, I'm not getting 4 alerts.  Anyway, I think you'll find this code to be a bit more efficient / clear:

```
$('.text').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
        alert('d');
    }
});
```

--edit--

Here's this code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1dgkyte/).

Comment: That's because you're typing more than 3 letters.  If you only want the event to trigger when there are exactly 3 letters, redefine the if to be `($(this).val().length == 3)`.